# Hive metadata permission issue

Tags: hadoop

We are getting this error on Hive, while creating a DB / table

```
hive> CREATE TABLE pokes (foo INT, bar STRING);                             
FAILED: Error in metadata: javax.jdo.JDOFatalDataStoreException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Could not create a validated object, cause: A read-only user or a user in a read-only database is not permitted to disable read-only mode on a connection.
NestedThrowables:
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Could not create a validated object, cause: A read-only user or a user in a read-only database is not permitted to disable read-only mode on a connection.
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

Hive log :

```
org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Could not create a validated object, cause: A read-only user or a user in a read-only database is not permitted to disable read-only mode on a connection.
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.NucleusJDOHelper.getJDOExceptionForNucleusException(NucleusJDOHelper.java:298)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:601)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.createPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:286)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:182)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper$16.run(JDOHelper.java:1958)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invoke(JDOHelper.java:1953)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.invokeGetPersistenceManagerFactoryOnImplementation(JDOHelper.java:1159)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:803)
    at javax.jdo.JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(JDOHelper.java:698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPMF(ObjectStore.java:234)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getPersistenceManager(ObjectStore.java:261)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.initialize(ObjectStore.java:196)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:171)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:62)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:117)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:354)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.executeWithRetry(HiveMetaStore.java:306)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:451)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:232)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.<init>(HiveMetaStore.java:197)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:108)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:1868)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:1878)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createTable(Hive.java:470)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Could not create a validated object, cause: A read-only user or a user in a read-only database is not permitted to disable read-only mode on a connection.
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:114)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.ConnectionFactoryImpl$ManagedConnectionImpl.getConnection(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:521)
    at org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.RDBMSStoreManager.<init>(RDBMSStoreManager.java:290)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry.createExecutableExtension(NonManagedPluginRegistry.java:588)
    at org.datanucleus.plugin.PluginManager.createExecutableExtension(PluginManager.java:300)
    at org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerFactoryImpl.initialiseStoreManager(ObjectManagerFactoryImpl.java:161)
    at org.datanucleus.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.freezeConfiguration(JDOPersistenceManagerFactory.java:583)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: Could not create a validated object, cause: A read-only user or a user in a read-only database is not permitted to disable read-only mode on a connection.
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1191)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:106)
    ... 52 more

2011-08-11 18:02:36,964 ERROR ql.Driver (SessionState.java:printError(343)) - FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

Comment: "Any help" isn't a question. Please edit this to include an actual question. Thank you and welcome to Server Fault. Please see the [FAQ] for details of how this site works.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the default Derby database for storing the Hive metadata, you must run Hive as a user with write permissions to the database file.

You can use any database with a JDBC driver for storing the metadata; if you're running a dev environment it's fine but anything that gets more usage should move to a different database. Choices include MySQL, Postgres, or Oracle if you're masochistic and enjoy overkill.